# Prove the boundedness of $R(z; D)v(x) = -i \int_x^{\infty} e^{i z(x-y)} v(y) dy, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}_+ \ a.e.$ in $L_1 (\mathbb{R}_+)$

Tags: integration, operator-theory, lp-spaces

Also, $Im z < 0$

That's what I've got:

$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Dd}{\operatorname{d}\!}
\begin{split}  
\|R(z; D)v(x)  \|_{L_1}  &= \int\limits_0^{+\infty} \Bigg|\int\limits_x^{+\infty} -i e^{iz(x-y)} v(y) \Dd y\Bigg|\Dd x \\ 
&\le \int\limits_0^{+\infty} \Bigg(\int\limits_x^{+\infty} |-i e^{iz(x-y)} v(y)| \Dd y \Bigg)\Dd x \\
&= \int\limits_0^{+\infty} \Bigg(\int\limits_x^{+\infty} |-i| |e^{iz(x-y)}| |v(y)| \Dd y \Bigg)\Dd x \\
& = \int\limits_0^{+\infty} \Bigg(\int\limits_x^{+\infty} e^{-(\mathrm{Im} z )(x-y)}|v(y)| \Dd y \Bigg)\Dd x 
\end{split}
$$

I don't know what to do further

Comment: I thought about changing the boundaries of integration without loss of generality, so maybe I could do something like this: $$= \int_0^{\infty} |v(y)| (\int_y^{\infty} e^{-(Im z )(x-y)} dx )dy = \frac{1}{Im z} \int_0^{\infty} |v(y)| dy = \frac{1}{Im z} \|v\|$$ This would mean, that $\|R(z;D)\| \le \frac{1}{Im z}$

Comment: Note also that if $\mathrm{Im}z<0$ then in your last formula you have $$ e^{-\text{Im}z (x-y)} = e^{-|\text{Im}z| |x-y|}\le e^{-|\text{Im}z|} \quad \forall y \in [x,+\infty[$$.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri You mean the equation after I changed the boundaries of integration, or right before that? Also, how could I use it here? Wouldn't I get a double integral with only $|v(y)|$ as the integrand (after $\le$)?

Comment: Right before that, and yes, you would get an iterated integral so the most promising way to proceed seems the application of Fubini-Tonelli in your comment. Thus it seems that $R(z,D)v(x)$ is $L_1$ bounded but not uniformly in $z$.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri the solution can't be $\|R(z;D)\| \le \frac{1}{Im z}$ because $Im z < 0$, but the norm is always $\ge 0$ !! So my approach must be wrong here